# API exception on constraint

Tags: rest-api, api

I need to prevent an object from being modified by any user in the salesforce.com website. The only way this object should be modified is through the REST API. We tried creating a constraint but it also affected API access. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the built in REST API you could create your own from Apex. That would give you control over object and field permissions in the Apex as the REST Apex web service will run in the system context. Use [`without sharing`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm) if you don't want sharing rules (record-level access) to apply to your custom REST service.

Then as [Bachovski suggests](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73909/102) you can lock down all standard UI and REST API access using the profiles.

Reference: [Exposing Data with Apex REST Web Service Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_exposing_data.htm)

> Invoking a custom Apex REST Web service method always uses system context. Consequently, the current user's credentials are not used, and any user who has access to these methods can use their full power, regardless of permissions, field-level security, or sharing rules. Developers who expose methods using the Apex REST annotations should therefore take care that they are not inadvertently exposing any sensitive data.
>
> ## Warning
>
> Apex class methods that are exposed through the Apex REST API don't enforce object permissions and field-level security by default. We recommend that you make use of the appropriate object or field describe result methods to check the current user’s access level on the objects and fields that the Apex REST API method is accessing. See [DescribeSObjectResult Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) and [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate profile only for the API user that has all rights to that object, and another profile which will have read-only access to that object. Then assign all those site users to the read-only profile.

If the same users have both UI and API access and you want to prevent them from creating, editing and deleting records within the UI, you will need to create some VF pages using the object's standard controller and override the New, Edit, Delete and Clone buttons for those users/profiles. [How to override page for some but not all users](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/overriding-a-page-for-some-but-not-all-users)

Comment: API user need full access form API but not from site. Additionally we need multiple user profiles so we can't create one for to be used for everyone. The only solution I see is a VisualForce page. Any other ideas?

Comment: Who's making modifications through the REST API? Is it 1 generic user or multiple users? If multiple, do they also have access through the UI?

Comment: We  have multiple users creating records of a custom object. They have access to the UI(salesforce.com?). This object should only be modifiable using the API.

Comment: As I said on all their profiles you need to give them read-only access for that particular object. I'm still not sure who's creating records through the API, those same users or different one/s?

Comment: The same users; so the problem is that if we add read-only access on their profile it prevents them form writing using the API.

Comment: Got it. I've updated my answer!